# Wrong library path when executing from Maven shaded .jar

Tags: java, maven, jar, jogl, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Though my application works fine from Eclipse, when using the Maven shaded plugin and 'run'ing the JAR I get an exception illustrating a failure to find a needed JOGL binary lib in the current working directory, rightfully because it is not in the current working directory, but in the root of the JAR itself.

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /path/to/working/dir/libgluegen-rt.so`

I have confirmed that the file is present at the JAR's root as expected.

My POM's plugin invocation:

```
<plugin>
 <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
 <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.1</version>
  <executions>
 <execution>
 <phase>package</phase>
 <goals>
  <goal>shade</goal>
 </goals>
 <configuration>
  <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
 <shadedClassifierName>RunMe</shadedClassifierName>
 <transformers>
   <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
   <mainClass>path.confirmed.to.work.RunMe</mainClass>
  </transformer>
</transformers>
 </configuration>
 </execution>
</executions>
 </plugin>
```

Manifest of my JAR:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_30
Built-By: me
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: path.confirmed.to.work.RunMe
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

Ideas? Suggestions?

UPDATE: Looks like the shaded plugin confuses JOGL's native lib unpacking. It is adding "linux-amd64 to the end of my jar's name, thinking this is the JOGL-only library jar!

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: /path/to/my/git/project/target/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-RunMe-natives-linux-amd64.jar (No such file or directory), while TempJarCache.bootstrapNativeLib() of jar:file:/path/to/my/git/project/terminal-recall/target/trcl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-RunMe-natives-linux-amd64.jar!/ (file:/path/to/my/git/project/target/ + trcl-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-RunMe-natives-linux-amd64.jar)
```

Comment: Well, as far as I know it's not possible to use a native library right from the JAR, it has to be extracted to the filesystem in a  destination system and loaded from there. There's maven-nar-plugin which is intended to simplify the packaging in this case

Comment: You're right; I totally forgot. It is starting to look like JOGL isn't unloading the libs to a temp or the temp location is not being added to the lib path.

Answer (score 1):

JOGL native lib loading is documented here:
https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling

One simple way to get a monolithic/Fat-Jar with the maven shade-plugin working, is by extracting the native libs from the lib folder (e.g. from
http://jogamp.org/deployment/jogamp-current/archive/jogamp-all-platforms.7z)
and putting them into your maven project's `src/main/resources/natives` folder.
This way the libraries end up in a `natives` subfolder in your Fat-Jar [as described](https://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/JogAmp_JAR_File_Handling#Fat-Jar)

Comment: Which then means you can no longer use Maven to manage the JOGL dependency as you're bypassing that and doing it manually.

Comment: true, it's not pretty

Answer (score 0):

Two things went wrong:

- JOGL is picky about the library JAR names and locations of its native libs within the JARs. JOGL still thinks it is running from its own JAR instead of a monolithic JAR, resulting in it looking for incorrect names and locations for its files to load into temp.
- JOGL has many native lib files of the same name and path in various JARs. When these get consolidated they result in name clash and most files end up not even being there.

My partial solution was to configure the POM to use copy-dependencies in the maven-dependency-plugin then reroute the classpath to a lib/ directory next to the JAR using maven-jar-plugin.

Comment: JOGL isn't picky, you have to follow the right rule to give GlueGen a chance to locate the JARs containing the native libraries so that it can extract them and load them. Following this rule (we already talked a lot about that on our official forum) allows to avoid any "name clash".